# Media keyboard shortcuts not working in Lenovo IdeaPad 330 15-ARR in Pop OS v20.04

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pop-os

Media keyboard shortcuts like play/pause, next, previous aren't working in Pop OS v20.04

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade system components from `Pop!_Shop` and reboot. Shortcuts will start working after reboot is done.